# Pandas: How to select the value of one column based on filtering another column?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume the following Pandas dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : [7, 2, 4, 20, 19, 5], 'color' : (['blue', 'red', 'gold', 'orange', 'silver', 'white']) })`

I'd like to get the value of the `id` column based on the minimum value of the `color` column.

I'm using the following code:

```
min_id = df['id'].min()    # gets the minimum value of the 'id' column
color = df.loc[df['id'] == min_id, 'color'].iloc[0]   # gets the 'color' value corresponding to the minimum 'id' value`
```

Is there a less 'hacky' way to do this?

Thanks in advance!
-Rachel

Comment: `df.loc[df['id'].idxmin(), 'color']`

Comment: Do you want to get the color of the min id or the id of the min color? You say one thing but code does another.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to acesss the value of a single cell, use [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

```
min_color = df.at[df['id'].idxmin(), 'color']
```

From the docs,

> Access a single value for a row/column label pair. Similar to `loc`, (...) use `at` if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or Series.

Comment: I find `.at` redundant when `.loc` already does the same thing when fed a single value of index and column.

Comment: @QuangHoang It's mostly a readability thing. When the reader reads `.loc`, you don't necessary, immediately know whether the mask used for the rows is a `pd.Series` or an index. Reading `.at` gives that immediately, and `.loc` doesn't. But yeah, super detail

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get the id for the minimum color value:

```py
min_color_id = df.loc[df['color'] == df['color'].min(), 'id'].iloc[0]
```

This line of code does the following:

- `df['color'].min()` gets the minimum value in the 'color' column (in alphabetical order).
- `df.loc[df['color'] == df['color'].min(), 'id']` gets the 'id' value(s) in the rows where the 'color' is equal to the minimum color value.
- `.iloc[0]` selects the first 'id' value in case there are multiple rows with the same minimum color value.